# Why does Win10 may hang at 'cmd /c type nul' command

Tags: chromium, gn

I have a chromium web-browser and a custom installer for it. Both are intended to be built with gn and autoninja. It seems the c++ part compiles fine but overall process hangs at last command here:

```
[40009/40017] cmd /c type nul > "obj/chrome/reorder_imports.stamp"
[40010/40017] cmd /c type nul > "obj/chrome/chrome.stamp"
[40011/40017] cmd /c type nul > "obj/chrome/installer/mini_installer/chrome_runtime_deps.stamp"
```

Here is a building command:

```
autoninja -v -C out\ReleaseX86 mini_installer
```

Why does it may hang? May be you know how to fix it?

**Update:** Ok, just in case I've ran build script one more time (without clearing project to avoid recompiling), it hangs at the same place:

```
"C:\Code\depot_tools\ninja.exe" -v -C out\ReleaseX86 mini_installer -j 10
ninja: Entering directory `out\ReleaseX86'
[1/11] C:/Code/depot_tools/bootstrap-2@3_8_10_chromium_23_bin/python/bin/python.exe ../../build/util/version.py --official -f ../../chrome/VERSION -o 81.39.4044.138.manifest ../../chrome/app/version_assembly/version_assembly_manifest.template
[2/11] cmd /c type nul > "obj/chrome/app/version_assembly/version_assembly_manifest.stamp"
[3/11] cmd /c type nul > "obj/chrome/reorder_imports.stamp"
[4/11] cmd /c type nul > "obj/chrome/chrome.stamp"
[5/11] cmd /c type nul > "obj/chrome/installer/mini_installer/chrome_runtime_deps.stamp"
```

Comment: You should post more output, it's not enough for us to find out why it's happening

Comment: I have no more output. That's all that console shows.

Comment: @Asesh, Added more output

Comment: Can't come to a conclusion with that output either. Can you build Chromium only?

Comment: @asesh, yes, browser compilation is fine, I can run it. Problem with my additional target